# How to find the actual width of element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying to find the actual width of given element and pop the alert which shows the actual width.

code i am using is here..

html element

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" style=";width:975px;border: 1px solid black;" id="menu_bar">
```

i am using this:

```
var widthofmenubar = $(this).find("#menu_bar").width;
```

Comment: Try $('#menu_bar').css('width');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
var widthofmenubar = $("#menu_bar").width();
```

and edit your html like

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" style="width:975px;border: 1px solid black;" id="menu_bar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `()`, you need to execute the `.width()` method.

```
var widthofmenubar = $(this).find("#menu_bar").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var widthofmenubar = $("#menu_bar").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:


First you edit your code, remove ';' after style attr

Correct Code is:

<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" style="width:975px;border: 1px solid black;" id="menu_bar">

Not

<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" style=";width:975px;border: 1px solid black;" id="menu_bar">

// Get Table Width by ID

var tableWidth = $('#menu_bar').css('width');

alert(tableWidth ); // will alert table width
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("#menu_bar").width();` for actual width that is displayed (rendered) and `$(this).find("#menu_bar").css('width')` for applied width

Answer (score 0):

there  is two methods in jquery for width;
1) .innerWidth
2) .outerwidth

**innerwidth calculate without margin width and outerWidth calculate with margin width.**

```
$('#menu_bar').innerWidth();
$('#menu_bar').outerWidth();
```